# Find all combinations of records which sums to zero in three array lists?

Tags: algorithm

Consider there are three array list each of equal length and having positive, negative and zero in them. I had to write a program to find combinations of which sum comes to zero. So basically, if the arrays were:-

```
A = {0, -1, 2}
B = {0, -1, -2}
C = {0, -2, 0}
```

O/P: A[0] + B[0] + C[0], A[2] + B[2] + C[2] etc.

I could think of two ways,
1. Have 3 for loops and calculate the sum using a[i] + b[j] + c[k], if zero print the index. 
   Big O will be O(N^3)
2. Have two for loop but use Binary Search to find the third element which would give the sum as zero. 
   Big O will be O(N^2LogN)

Any other ways?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Based on the answers given below, my first soln is the fastest possible. But if the question is about "finding" the number of combinations and **NOT** printing them, then please see Grigor Gevorgyan answer below.

Comment: Are you only interested in sets that contain exactly one element from each list?

Comment: You cannot possibly beat `Omega(N^3)` worst case runtime if you have to output all triples that sum to zero, because if all three input sets consist solely of zeros, then all combinations sum to zero and hence the *output* is of size `Omega(N^3)`. In that case even though the binary search finds the range you're after in `O(log N)` time, it's `Omega(N)` time to traverse it.

Comment: I have a O(n^2) complexity solution but only if some assumption allowed. See plz http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603110/538514

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done in ***O(n^2)*** with *2 pointers method*.

Sort the arrays. Now do following:
Set ***ans = 0***.
Have an external loop running through array ***a*** with index ***i***. Now set ***j = 0, k = n - 1***.
Look at ***sum = a[ i ] + b[ j ] + c[ k ]***.
 If ***sum < 0***, increase ***j***.
 If ***sum > 0*** decrease ***k***.
 If ***sum == 0***, find the range of elements equal to ***b[ j ]*** and ***c[ k ]*** and add ranges lengths product to the answer. Then set ***j*** and ***k*** to first elements out of that ranges.
 This works because arrays are sorted and addition is a linear function.
Internal part runs in **O(n)**, with overall **O(n^2)** complexity.

Example code in C++:

```cpp
sort( a, a + n );
sort( b, b + n );
sort( c, c + n );
ans = 0;
for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
   j = 0, k = n - 1;
   while( j < n && k > 0 )
   {
      sum = a[ i ] + b[ j ] + c[ k ];
      if( sum < 0 ) ++j;
          else if( sum > 0 ) --k;
          else 
          { 
             // find the equal range
             for( jj = j; jj < n && b[ jj ] == b[ j ]; ++jj );
             for( kk = k; kk >= 0 && c[ kk ] == c[ k ]; --kk );
             // add pairs quantity from these ranges
             ans += ( jj - j ) * ( k - kk );
             j = jj, k = kk;
          }
}
```

***Note***: Sorting of array ***a*** is not necessary, just did it to look good :)

Comment: It misses some valid i,j,k triples. See Steve Jessop's comment to the question

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oh, thanks, I forgot about the same values. Edited the answer to consider equal ranges.

Comment: thanks for the help. I had also mentioned sorting in my answer - to get the soln faster. But noticing an issue, for my given example, it doesn't print a[0], b[0] and c[0]; a[2], b[2], c[0] combinations. I am trying to look, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @parsh: Do you need to have all the combinations printed or just their quantity ? If first, it cannot be done faster than O(n^3), because there're exactly n^3 combinations in case of all elements are equal, see Steve Jessop's comment.

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan: yes i was asked to print all combinations and not their quantity. So then as per your + Steve's comment, my first solution is the best possible?

Comment: @parsh: If you have to print them - yes, it's impossible to be faster than O(n^3).

Comment: Thanks again. I will edit my question to mention your answer as a soln to a diff problem. Not sure if this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I think this 3SUM:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

To quote the wikipedia writeup:

> There is a simple algorithm to solve 3SUM in O(n2) time by first hashing each element in the array, finding all possible pairs, then finally checking for existence of the remaining value (which is simply the negative of the sum of each pair) using the hash table.

Comment: Yes, but only if you are supposed to read data into hashtable initially. Exploring third array list and putting it into a hashtable costs O(n) so no speed ups. See my answer plz http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603110/538514

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be to check all the subsets, but this has very poor runtime.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Subset.html
Without further restriction, I believe this is the NP complete subset sum problem. There is a solution related to the knapsack problem that gives a decent solution. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Do you need to find all combinations that sum to 0 or just a single one or just a solution with 3 elements?

solutions should be {{A[0]},{B[0]}, {C[0]}, {C[2]}, {A[0],B[0]},{A[0],B[0],C[0]},{A[0],B[0],C[0],C[2]},{A[1],B[1],A[2]},{A[2],B[2]} and so forth}

Comment: I'm fairly sure the intention is that each of the "sums" we're looking for is a sum of exactly one element from each of `A`, `B`, `C`. Otherwise there's no point having three input sequences in the first place, we could have just had a single input sequence of size 9.

Comment: fair enough, that makes it a much easier problem... could have been a trick question, or I could just be making things more complicated by default :]

Answer (score 1):

This solution has a speed up only if you are reading given to you data into array lists from some storage e.g. file or any input stream by yourself. Replacing third array list with `hashtable` gives you a constant time for looking up a third component of zero-sum. In your two nested loops each time getting new pair `a[i]+b[j]` you are looking up in hashtable for `c[n0]=-a[i]+b[j]` that takes `O(1)`. So the total time complexity is O(n^2). Let me clarify that this solutions helps only if you are allowed for mastering with the reading process and doesn't speed up anything if you are already given with array lists.

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution, not sure if the interviewer would have accepted this though. But thanks.